# How to join and filter between 3 tables with ecto query expressions

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I have 3 schemas: `Post`, `Author`, `Assistant`.

`Post` belongs_to `:author`

`Author` has_many `:posts` and has_one `:assistant`

`Assistant` belongs_to `:author`

I want to build a query that only gets `Post`s where the `Author` has an `Assistant`.

So far, I've only been able to join the `Author` to the `Post`. I can't figure out how to query `Post`s based on the presence of an `Author`'s `Assistant`.

```
Post
|> join(:inner, [p], a in assoc(p, :author))
|> Repo.all()
```

**Edit 1**

I think I've made some progress and this query seems to be working with the couple of records I have in the db right now, but not sure if it's the conventional way.

```
Post
|> join(:inner, [p], a in assoc(p, :author), as: :author)
|> join(:left, [author: a], asst in assoc(a, :assistant), as: :assistant)
|> where([assistant: asst], not is_nil(asst.id)))
|> Repo.all()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think a left join is necessary for this scenario. You should be able to inner join on all of the tables because an inner join will indicate the presence of an assistant and rule out any possibility of getting an author without an assistant. You should be able to write something like this:

```
query = from(p in Post,
  join: a in Author,
  on: a.id == p.author_id,
  join: ast in Assistant,
  on: ast.author_id == a.id,
  # See notes below about the distinct
  distinct: p.id
)

Repo.all(query)
```

Because you inner join on all of the tables it indicates that a post must have an author and an author must have an assistant to be a resulting row in this query. If you wanted to do something like figure out all of the posts that have an author with no assistant you would want to left join.

**Note about `distinct`:**

I put the distinct clause in case you have multiple assistants assigned to an author in your database (which would indicate bad data) and posts in the result set would be duplicated. This is because a `has_one` relationship is just a constrained `has_many`. If you have a unique index on the `author_id` column in the `assistants` table, you do not need the distinct clause. If you do not have a unique index you can write this in a migration:

```
create unique_index("assistants", :author_id)
```

You should probably do this for all of your `has_one` relationships.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This might be an overkill in this particular case, but it’s always easier to decouple such queries into [subqueries](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html?#subquery/2).

```
authors_with_assistants =
  from a in Author, where: not is_nil(a.assistant_id)
```

or

```
authors_with_assistants =
  from a in Author,
  left_join: asst in assoc(a, :assistant)
```

and

```
posts =
  from p in Post,
    join: a in subquery(authors_with_assistants),
    on: p.author_id == a.id

Repo.all(posts)
```

Also, chaining joins with a condition on the latter would also work (meaning your query in *Edit1* section looks fine.)

Comment: Thanks for helping out. The "authors"  table doesn't have an `assistant_id` column, but instead the "assistants" table has an `author_id` column.

Comment: Then do a subquery as inner join `authors` to `assistants`, it does not make much difference in the approach. That’s exactly why I suggested decoupling: no matter how you have constructed the subquery, the resulting query stays intact.